# How to add new data to existing dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've created empty dataframe that I have to fill.

```
d = {'A': [], 'B': [], 'C': []}
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Then I am assigning data like this:

```
dataframe['A'] = some_list_1a
dataframe['B'] = some_list_1b
dataframe['C'] = some_list_1c
```

So my dataframe is filled like this:

```
 A      B     C
----------------
val1  val1  val1
val1  val1  val1
val1  val1  val1
```

Then I have to add new values from list but the previous way is not working:
`dataframe['A'] = some_list_2a`  etc.

That's what I want:

```
 A      B     C
----------------
val1  val1  val1
val1  val1  val1
val1  val1  val1
val2  val2  val2
val2  val1  val2
val2  val2  val2
```

(val1 - values from first lists, val2 - values from second lists)

I know I can make second dataframe and use `concat` method, but is there another way of doing it?

Comment: Better directly create the DataFrame from the combinations of lists rather that trying to insert the data

Answer (score 1):

Create dictionary with all joined lists first and then call DataFrame is fastest and recommended way, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24871316/2901002):

```
d = {'A': some_list_1a + some_list_2a, 
     'B': some_list_1b + some_list_2b,
     'C': some_list_1c + some_list_2c}
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

If need append dict of list in loop:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

#some loop
for x in iter:
    d[col_name].append(sublist)
    
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Comment: what if I don't have both lists (1 and 2) at the beginning? (I should mention that earlier)

Comment: @suziex - then not create `df`, first working with `d` - add sublists and last call DataFrame